# Selenium grid on Virtual XP machine - connection error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am running my tests against FF 6.0 on virtual Windows XP machine. The winner-line

```
 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.5.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.1.149:4444/grid/register -port 5558 -host 10.0.2.15 -browser "browserName=firefox, version=6, platform=WINDOWS"
```

Gives me the following result:

```
17:53:22.667 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:5559
17:53:22.667 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@5dccce3c
17:53:22.668 INFO - using the json request : {"class":"org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest","capabilities":[{" version":"6","browserName":"firefox"," platform":"WINDOWS"}],"configuration":{"port":5559,"host":"192.168.1.135","hubHost":"192.168.1.149","registerCycle":5000,"hub":"http://192.168.1.149:4444/grid/register","url":"http://10.0.2.15:5559/wd/hub","register":true,"singleWindow":"-role","proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.WebDriverRemoteProxy","maxSession":5,"browser":"browserName=firefox, version=6, platform=WINDOWS","role":"webdriver","hubPort":4444}}
17:53:22.669 INFO - starting auto register thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
17:53:22.669 INFO - Registering the node to hub :http://192.168.1.149:4444/grid/register
```

Unfortunately, it never finishes by

```
17:53:25.486 INFO - Executing: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.Status@43a6684f at URL: /status)
17:53:25.488 INFO - Done: /status
```

It sort of hangs up on the word "register".

Consequently, when running the tests I get an error:

```
** Erubis 2.6.6
Loaded suite test/selenium/website_smoke_tests
Started
E
Finished in 21.022798 seconds.

  1) Error:
test_top_page(WebsiteSmokeTest):
Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2)
```

The node is visible on http://192.168.1.149:4444/grid/console.

Comment: What version of grid are you using?  The one shipped in Selenium 2.6.0 fixed a lot of network-related issues.

Comment: selenium-server-standalone-2.2.0.jar that implies "Use this if you want to use the Selenium RC or Remote WebDriver or use Grid 2 without needing any additional dependencies "

Comment: Tried selenium-server-standalone-2.6.0, as well as new release of Webdriver 2.6.0. No help. I start to lose hope... The strange thing, that the node gets registered at the hub but the execution of org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler does not happen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is solved. It was the error of my connection. Have never gotten the response from Hub to Node on the VM. My bad.

Comment: Can you explain what the fix was?

Comment: I had the same issue on VirtualBox. The solution was to change the network settings from NAT to Bridged Adapter.

Comment: We need to know what the fix was, not what the problem was